# Ember.js, how to get the value of a model in the store

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, ember.js

i am trying to build an android app using phonegap and ember.js. 
There I have user and I want to know the usernames.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model : function(){
    var store = this.get('store');
    var tmp = this.get('store').find('user',{'username': 'test'}).then(function(items) {
          return items.map(function(item) {
                return [item.get('username')];
              })
            });
    for(var key in tmp){
        console.log("TMP key:" + key + " value: " + tmp[key]);
    }

    return tmp;
}
});
```

This model function works fine. I get all usernames in my index template. But how to get the usernames in my model function?
The log looks like this:

```
TMP key:finally value: function (callback, Label){
       var constructor = this.construcor;
       return this.then(function(value) {
              return constructor.cast(callback)()).then(function(){
                       return value;
                       });
       }, function(reason) {
               return constructor.cast(callback()).then(function(){
                       throw reason;
               });
       }, label);
       }
```

The first value of tmp is the function(...), the second value looks similar. So how do i get the usernames from the store? I want something like tmp = ["test","test",etc.]

my model is just:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
     username : DS.attr('string'),
 });
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

find returns a promise, you can't evaluate the results of the promise until it's been resolved.

This won't happen until you've left the model hook (it's asynchronous).

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(){
    var store = this.get('store'),
        promise = store.find('user',{'username': 'test'}),
        promiseResults = promise.then(function(items) {
            return items.map(function(item) {
                     return [item.get('username')];
                   })
            });

    promiseResults.then(function(results){
      // this codes executes asynchronously after the model hook
      for(var key in results){
        console.log("TMP key:" + key + " value: " + results[key]);
      }
    });


    return promiseResults ;
  }
});
```